# How do I make sure that Linux drivers are installed correctly?

Tags: linux, driver, nvidia

I am installing CUDA 5.5. But before that I had to install drivere. I did that. is there any command in Ubuntu 12.04, that can tell  me if the drivers are correctly installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the `lsmod` command whether the driver modules are present or not.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/338907/how-to-install-cuda-5-5-under-ubuntu-12-04-lts-64-bit This might help you more.